# In which folder do i need to be for installing git on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, sudo, apt

I am new to Ubuntu and want to do *sudo apt install git*.

**Do I need to be in root directory or in my home directory for that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need to be in any specific directory to call this command.** You can see this by calling

```
sudo apt-file update
apt-file list git
```

which lists all files that would be installed as part of *git* package. Note that the output is irrelevant to your current location (i.e. these files have **absolute** location).